# Blocked from accessing a cross origin frame

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe

When I put allow-same-origin, it works but when I remove it, I have :

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:****" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

I need just to allow allow-scripts and allow-modals.

Here is the working code :

```
function updateIframe(iframe) {
   iframe[0].contentWindow.getMinHeight();
}
```

I search on the forum but the protocol and the domain of iframe and of the site is the same. I don't understand where can be the error.

The parent : `http://localhost****`

The iframe src : `http://localhost:****/My/path/for/the/file`

Port is the same and I need to avoid allow-same-origin for the cookie security

Answer (score 0):

If the ****'s are for different ports, note that the port must also be the same for it to count as a same-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

If `allow-same-origin` isn't an option, try `allow-origin` and pass in `http://localhost:3000` or whatever your port number is. You'll obviously have to change it to the production URL for deployment.